# Ubuntu 14.04.2 Trusty with two gpu cards, desktop on wrong screen

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a fresh install dualbooot, first I installed windows 7, then ubuntu trusty desktop 14.04.2., then I was able to get amd catalyst 14.9 for linux x64 working. When doing this with both my amd r9 cards installed, the post, operating sytem selection,  windows 7, and ubuntu login are all on card one. The I login and desktop goes to card two.  I want two ards for the oclhashcat performance, but im only planning on using it on a kvm with one screen. The cards are digital only dvi-d with some mini-display ports also. Itry to put up dual screens, but the first screen is only shell after logging in if I ctrl+alt+f1 - f6. ctr+alt+f7 gets me back to desktop gui on the second one. AMD catalyst shows a grey-out second monitor (numbered #0) and ubuntu display settings don't show a second monitor. How can I get desktop to be on the second screen?